# Volley: onResponse in JsonObjectRequest delayed request

Tags: java, android, json, get, android-volley

Am a newbie to the Volley library, I'm creating a simple Android app that takes data from an API that generates in JSON. After debugging, only this particular function `fetchAccD` mentioned below have delay issues with Android Volley. Other functions within this Activity and other Activities which implies the `JsonObjectRequest` works perfectly fine.

```
{
    "Account": {
        "remarks": "NIL"
        "uname": "admin"
        "pword": null // value not to be shown
        "key": 1316451
        "name": "msummons sudo"
    }
}
```

Here's my current code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
    uName = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
    // reset session
    authidCoDe = 0;

    // invoke session
    Account account = fetchAccD(uName);

    if (account != null) {
        authidCoDe = account.getKey();
        ...


// init user details before loading
private final Account fetchAccD (String userN) {
    final Account account = new Account();
    requestQueue = null;
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String urlConstruct = *json url*;

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlConstruct,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("Account");
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                        account.setUname(jsonObject.optString("uname"));
                     // account.setPword(jsonObject.optString("pword"));
                        account.setKey(jsonObject.optInt("key"));
                        account.setName(jsonObject.optString("name"));
                        account.setRemarks(jsonObject.optString("remarks"));
                        requestQueue.stop();
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fetch failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        requestQueue.stop();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fetch failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            requestQueue.stop();
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    return account;
}
```

When invoking `fetchAccD`, the code runs perfect up to

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlConstruct,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
```

Then it proceeds to `onCreate` where it runs after the `fetchAccD` method

```
if (account != null) {
    authidCoDe = account.getKey();
    ...
```

Before it goes back to the rest of the `onResponse` method in the `fetchAccD` method.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("Account");
        ...
```

I've used `JsonObjectRequest` GET for most of my functions to fetch JSON, this problem only happens just for the `fetchAccD` function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onResponse` is asynchronous, it will be invoked when the server returns a response.

So you should wait the response before doing this:

```
if (account != null) {
    authidCoDe = account.getKey();
    ...
}
```

---

`onCreate` should do:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
    uName = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
    // reset session
    authidCoDe = 0;

    // invoke session
    fetchAccD(uName);
}
```

In `onResponse` you can do:

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("Account");
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
        account.setUname(jsonObject.optString("uname"));
     // account.setPword(jsonObject.optString("pword"));
        account.setKey(jsonObject.optInt("key"));
        account.setName(jsonObject.optString("name"));
        account.setRemarks(jsonObject.optString("remarks"));
        useAccount(account);
        requestQueue.stop();
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fetch failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        requestQueue.stop();
    }
}
```

Define a method `useAccount`:

```
private void useAccount(Account account) {
    if (account != null) {
        authidCoDe = account.getKey();
        ...
    }
}
```

And `fetchAccD` does not need to return a value, you can make it `void`.

Comment: Thanks! It does work but that means, my `onCreate` method can only function up to the `fetchAccD(uName);`? Or no? :)

Comment: You can add more things after `fetchAccD`. When I say that your Activity should wait the response it doesn't mean that you can't do other things meanwhile. Please mark the answer as accepted if it works for you, thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciated your help, here's my approval :)